# Crash in PSPDFKit SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, pspdfkit, xcode6.4

I integrate PSPDFKit framework.But when I run my project,it crashes anf shows +[PSPDFAnnotationGroupItem inkConfigurationBlock]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x517f74 (lldb)  .

I follow their integration process but it's not work for me.

Comment: Did you contact their support?

Comment: Yah...they give me a solution way but it's not work.

Comment: Maybe you should ask again. Nobody but them have insights on their framework and given your error message all we can say is: there is some problem.

Answer (score 3):

We're already working with you on our support channel over at https://support.pspdfkit.com - The issue was that the -ObjC linker flag was missing in your configuration.

Comment: Yes.. thanks for this answer.I post this question stackoverflow to familiar with some people who knows about PSPDFKit integration process. :)